# Event notification error in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have written code for event notification which is shown below. I have set event as date and time. At that particular time I have specified some actions like storing some information in another table called PT. I am not getting any errors but after that event time also information is not storing in PT.
Any ideas...

```
DROP EVENT `t1` ;

CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` EVENT `t1` ON SCHEDULE AT '2014-02-17 03:43:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE DISABLE DO BEGIN INSERT INTO PT( pname, Dname, Test_name )
SELECT Patient.pname, Doctor.Docname, Tests.Test_name
FROM Patient, Doctor, Tests, Assist
WHERE (Assist.Date = '2014-02-17 03:43:00') AND (Assist.Pid = Patient.pid) AND (Assist.Did= Doctor.Did) AND (Assist.Tid = Tests.Tid);

END
```

Comment: here what's role for sql-server tag..?

Answer (score 0):

You need *Event Scheduler Configuration* done for the event to work.

Default state of Event Scheduler is *DISABLED*.
You require to enable it by any of the following statements.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
SET @@global.event_scheduler = ON;
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
SET @@global.event_scheduler = 1;
```

When the Event Scheduler is *ON*, the event scheduler thread is listed in the output of `SHOW PROCESSLIST` as a daemon process, and its state is represented as shown here:

```
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     Id: 1
   User: root
   Host: localhost
     db: NULL
Command: Query
   Time: 0
  State: NULL
   Info: show processlist
*************************** 2. row ***************************
     Id: 2
   User: event_scheduler
   Host: localhost
     db: NULL
Command: Daemon
   Time: 3
  State: Waiting for next activation
   Info: NULL
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Once the Event Scheduler is set ON, you would see it working.

**Refer to** : [MySQL Event Scheduler Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-configuration.html)